# Corrupted file using request js

Tags: node.js, requestjs

I am using request js to download a file.

```
function requ(){
    const options = {
        uri: `api/tasks/${id}/attachments/${attachmentId}`
    }
    return rp.get(options)
 }
```

My question is:

why piping to "res" like requ().pipe(res) works and returning the result of the request above using "send" like

```
requ().then((result)=>{
    //here result is the file's representing string
    res.send(result)

})
```

don't?

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs = require('fs');
requ().then((result) => {
    //here result is the file's representing string
    const path = __dirname + '/tempFiles' + Date.now(); // a temporary file to send it 
    fs.writeFile(path, result, function(err) {
        if(err) throw err;
        return res.sendFile(path);
    })
});
```

Read More About [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html), [link 2](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_filesystem.asp)

Answer (score 0):

My file was being corrupted because request was converting the response body to utf8. Using:

```
const options = {
    uri: `api/tasks/${id}/attachments/${attachmentId}`,
    encoding:null
}
```

fixed the problem